# how to override guard function in rails graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have a return type for my query as follows:

```
 field :one, [Types::Objects::SpecificType], null: true
 field :two, [Types::Objects::SpecificType], null: true
```

```
class SpecificType < Types::Objects::SomeClass
  field :answers, [Types::Objects::AnswerType], null: true, method: :answers, guard: :show_answers?
end
```

as you can see I have 2 different fields that return the same type and they have the same guard
I want to override the logic for the guard in show_answers? but I don't really know how to do it, because I want field :one to have different guard on answers other than field :two

the project is huge and this is just a simple example to demonstrate my problem

I tried to override the show_answers? guard or pass it as params but couldn't